# Server resources (CPU/Memory) Meteor DDP connection

Tags: meteor, memory, resources, cpu, ddp

I'm trying to find information about the influence of DDP on the CPU/memory usage of the server.

Online I can't find much literature/info about this subject. Only thing I found is that when you send a lot of data to the client, the client CPU usage will increase ([see link for more details](https://bulletproofmeteor.com/basics/send-less-data))

For the server I guess DDP would use more resources of the server then just a plain websocket connection would do, since it's working on top of websockets (or tries to imitate a websocket connection over other connection techniques - SockJS).

Next to that I'm guessing the use of server resources will be higher in comparison to short-, longpolling and websockets because DDP offers more functionalities like the RPC (Remote Procedure Call) and Pub/Sub on data from the MongoDB. But what part of DDP will cause the higher use of server resources?

Question :

- Why the CPU and memory usage of the server will be higher then other
  live data techniques?

The image below is an overview of the DDP connection of Meteor

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: @AndyK this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites your not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat if it is a poor fit, where should he go?

Comment: @AndyK see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Comment: That does not answer the question

Comment: @AndyK I just posted my question at the the Software Engineering forum of StackExchange. Hopefully somebody can help me there with my question.

Comment: hey @TimDijkhuizen, if software engineering is not willing to help, you can ask Quora. However as Gnat implied yesterday, you need to be sure of where you want to go and Tbh, software engineering may not be the optimized forum to ask your question. However, in the lack of other forums that can help, this is still imo the best one to ask. The aim of all stack forums is to have questions and answers that are as good in quality as possible. Sorry for the long rant.

Comment: @gnat I got your point that we need good contents and with the tidal wave of bad questions or bad answers, the reflex would be to ditch everything that it is not SE 'kosher' but yet, it is also a forum for help... Sorry for my comment yesterday.

Comment: II moved my question right now to the Network Engineering forum of StackExchange. I hope it's more relevant over there.